# R: singular convergence in mixed effect model

Tags: r, mixed-model, convergence

I have an experiment that is designed as 6 blocks of 4 plots each, with two treatments (W_add and P_add) plus combination of treatments and control. The data are flux measurements taken during 9 campaigns.

I want to see if the treatments had a significant effect on the fluxes over time.

Here is my code:

```
library(nlme)
library(car)

setwd("[...]")

data<-read.csv("season_flux.csv")

flux = data$CO2_NEE #CO2_ER, CO2_NEE, GEP, or CH4

model = lme(flux ~ W_add * P_add * DOY, random = ~1|block/plot, 
                     corr = corGaus (form = ~DOY|block/plot, nugget = TRUE), 
                     data = data, na.action = na.omit, method = "REML")

contrasts(data$W_add) <- contr.sum
contrasts(data$P_add) <- contr.sum

Anova <- Anova(model, type = "III", test.statistic = "F")
summary(Anova)
print(Anova)
```

And here is the head of my data

```
  DOE       DOY   plot type CO2_ER  CO2_NEE        GEP        CH4   W_add  P_add
1 0.4831486 179   25    D 4.615219       NA -0.1560684 -2.4904458    NW    NP
2 0.4885537 179   25    L       NA 4.459151         NA         NA    NW    NP
3 0.4948533 179   26    D 4.178014       NA -1.3169272 -0.9756073     W    NP
4 0.5003533 179   26    L       NA 2.861087         NA         NA     W    NP
5 0.5069753 179   27    D 3.524708       NA -0.9260853 -1.2356268    NW     P
6 0.5123025 179   27    L       NA 2.598623         NA         NA    NW     P
  treatment block   PAR soil_moist soil_T_2 soil_T_5
1         C     1    NA   21.80000      4.6      3.0
2         C     1 206.2   21.80000      4.6      3.0
3         W     1    NA   32.13333      4.2      3.2
4         W     1 278.8   32.13333      4.2      3.2
5         P     1    NA   26.93333      4.2      2.6
6         P     1 303.4   26.93333      4.2      2.6
```

And the summary of my data:

```
      DOE               DOY             plot       type        CO2_ER      
 Min.   : 0.4832   Min.   :179.0   Min.   :25.00   D:214   Min.   :-1.044  
 1st Qu.:20.4576   1st Qu.:199.0   1st Qu.:31.00   L:182   1st Qu.: 2.320  
 Median :34.5007   Median :212.0   Median :37.00           Median : 4.050  
 Mean   :36.5580   Mean   :214.2   Mean   :36.57           Mean   : 4.376  
 3rd Qu.:54.6842   3rd Qu.:233.0   3rd Qu.:43.00           3rd Qu.: 5.268  
 Max.   :68.7054   Max.   :246.0   Max.   :48.00           Max.   :23.932  
                                                           NA's   :186     
    CO2_NEE            GEP                CH4           W_add    P_add   
 Min.   :-2.796   Min.   :-13.2704   Min.   :-8.03760   NW:199   NP:195  
 1st Qu.: 1.187   1st Qu.: -2.9642   1st Qu.:-2.56166   W :197   P :201  
 Median : 2.273   Median : -1.3474   Median :-1.85111                    
 Mean   : 2.541   Mean   : -2.1185   Mean   :-2.07423                    
 3rd Qu.: 3.587   3rd Qu.: -0.1575   3rd Qu.:-1.15698                    
 Max.   :10.662   Max.   :  0.0000   Max.   : 0.02807                    
 NA's   :214      NA's   :217        NA's   :189                         
 treatment     block            PAR           soil_moist       soil_T_2     
 C :101    Min.   :1.000   Min.   : 149.8   Min.   : 7.40   Min.   : 4.200  
 P : 98    1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.: 429.4   1st Qu.:13.98   1st Qu.: 7.000  
 W : 94    Median :4.000   Median : 659.5   Median :16.30   Median : 8.600  
 WP:103    Mean   :3.515   Mean   : 713.0   Mean   :16.38   Mean   : 8.624  
           3rd Qu.:5.000   3rd Qu.:1012.4   3rd Qu.:18.37   3rd Qu.: 9.900  
           Max.   :6.000   Max.   :1594.2   Max.   :32.13   Max.   :17.700  
                           NA's   :24                                       
    soil_T_5     
 Min.   : 2.600  
 1st Qu.: 5.900  
 Median : 6.800  
 Mean   : 6.809  
 3rd Qu.: 7.700  
 Max.   :11.000  
 NA's   :2
```

I get the following output:

```
Error in lme.formula(flux ~ W_add * P_add * DOY, random = ~1 | block/plot,  :
  nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
  message = singular convergence (7)
```

The error does not happen with another flux than CO2_NE or if I use another correlation. This error also does not happen if I delete the last line of my data, which looks like this:

```
68.70536503,246,48,L,,2.27190302873568,,,W,NP,W,6,450.2,17.0333333333333,9.2,7.1
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post a link to your dataset ?

Comment: I have uploaded it in my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/567g3k1nug7k4kx/season_flux.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fitted the model using `lme4` and found that there is no variation at the `block` level:

```
> m0 <- lmer(flux ~ W_add * P_add * DOY  + (1 | block) + (1 | plot), data = data)
> summary(m0)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: flux ~ W_add * P_add * DOY + (1 | block) + (1 | plot)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 762.1

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.85542 -0.64230  0.01562  0.52262  2.95350 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 plot     (Intercept) 1.817    1.348   
 block    (Intercept) 0.000    0.000   
 Residual             2.781    1.668   
Number of obs: 182, groups:  plot, 24; block, 6

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)        2.034342   2.491762   0.816
W_addW             3.257081   3.731735   0.873
P_addP             2.614168   3.620830   0.722
DOY                0.002315   0.011295   0.205
W_addW:P_addP     -4.798173   5.210949  -0.921
W_addW:DOY        -0.017029   0.016990  -1.002
P_addP:DOY        -0.012404   0.016438  -0.755
W_addW:P_addP:DOY  0.025649   0.023681   1.083
```

`lme4` fits the model without convergence problems, though it is unable to handle the correlation structure that you used with `nlme`. However, if we fit the model in `nlme` without `block` in the random structure we obtain very similar results to `lme4`:

```
> model = lme(flux ~ W_add * P_add * DOY, random = ~1|plot, corr = corGaus (form = ~DOY|plot, nugget = TRUE), data = data, na.action = na.omit, method = "REML")
> summary(model)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: data 
      AIC      BIC    logLik
  785.879 823.7877 -380.9395

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | plot
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    1.345257 1.671597

Correlation Structure: Gaussian spatial correlation
 Formula: ~DOY | plot 
 Parameter estimate(s):
       range       nugget 
3.176300e+00 3.482499e-06 
Fixed effects: flux ~ W_add * P_add * DOY 
                      Value Std.Error  DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)        1.954598  2.516343 154  0.7767615  0.4385
W_addW             3.319879  3.771597  20  0.8802317  0.3892
P_addP             2.596632  3.656539  20  0.7101338  0.4858
DOY                0.002818  0.011427 154  0.2466313  0.8055
W_addW:P_addP     -4.852672  5.262861  20 -0.9220597  0.3675
W_addW:DOY        -0.017406  0.017206 154 -1.0116291  0.3133
P_addP:DOY        -0.012394  0.016626 154 -0.7454639  0.4571
W_addW:P_addP:DOY  0.025926  0.023957 154  1.0822138  0.2808
```

The random effects are almost identical and the fixed effects are very similar.

This leads me to believe that `lme` fails to converge because the optimizer gets stuck due to an estimated variance component being close to zero. I do not know enough about `nlme` to diagnose this any further.

Comment: Thank you very much!
If I understand correctly, you are saying that there is no point in nesting the data in blocks? I was expecting some spatial variation as the field site was not completely homogeneous.

Comment: That's what my analysis suggests, yes. The variation at the plot level is almost as large as the residual variation, but `lme4` estimated zero variation at the block level. This might be due to missing data, so one further approach is to use multiple imputation

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I have a better idea of what I'm doing now ;-)